# DUPLICATE_VALUE Flow version is not unique when Activating Journey

Tags: journeybuilder

I have a journey built against salesforce Contact Records which is triggered when a contact record is created. This journey will activate just fine.

However, when I try to add a goal based on a second event also against a salesforce contact record being updated, I receive the following error when trying to activate the journey.

DUPLICATE_VALUE;The fullName: JBSystemFlow_Contact-109 for Flow version is not unique.;;Flow Save failed.

In both cases my salesforce contact is updated by external systems using Rest APIs and my journeys need to detect those changes and reach goal states as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to fix:

1. Log in to your Salesforce Org.
2. Click Setup.
3. Type Custom Settings in the Quick Find Box and click it.
4. Click Manage next to **et4ae_Configuration**
5. Click Edit
6. Click the checkbox for **Enable JB Platform Events** and click Save.